# Is there any way to auto configure OCaml Merlin?

Tags: ocaml, merlin

It seems that Merlin requires manually configuring it using the `.merlin` file. IntelliSense does not require anything like that when using VisualStudio (at least when using it with languages like C++/C#/F#). This includes finding implementations of third party libraries. I imagine that this is partly by using the `*proj`, `packages.config` files and maybe data emitted by the compiler (but I'm only guessing). Is there anything similar for Merlin (maybe through using the `.opam` files or an OCaml compiler)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your code with dune - https://dune.readthedocs.io/ - then it will generate the merlin configuration for you.